# .htaccess help required for apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

I searching for a redirection code for my url:

what I want is when some one search in my site it should redirect

example: if some one search google.com on mysite

then in address line it should look like www.mydomain.com/google.com

can be in $_POST method or $_GET

how do I do that??

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google\.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/google.com [R,L]
```

in an `.htaccess` file might work, i have not tested it.

you could try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /(.*)\/search\.php\?q=(www\.)?([^/\ ]+)[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/%1 [R,L]
```

this link also has some other example 'smart' `.htaccess` rules: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /search\.php\?q=(www\.)?([^/\ ]+)[^\ ]*\ HTTP/

this is for request of any kind of search domains..but what I dont know is how do I convert to  http://www.mydomain.com/domain.com

Comment: added another potential answer

Comment: nop it doesnt work

Comment: does it do /anything/ can you provide more information as to how it doesn't help? maybe enable logging for RewriteRules `RewriteLog file-path` and `RewriteLogLevel 9` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html you also have to be willing to play with the regular expression in the `RewriteCond` to see if you can at least get it to trigger. i don't know where you got that pattern, so i have no idea if it should work or not, you provided it.